# Error is being occurred while performing step 6 Start REST Client Data Generator in the installation of demo appsensor

Tags: spring, maven, cmd

When i execute this command mvn spring-boot:run after reached into the recommended directory, The execution starts but never ends (means commands on cmd are running continuously). I have
tried many times but same error is being occurred. I am following the demo guide (https://github.com/jtmelton/appsensor/blob/master/sample-apps/DemoSetup.md) which has came with appsensor code.
Kindly give poosible solutions.

Here is my error message
[image: screen shot of that error]

Comment: This is not your problem. You are trying to do something else.